# how to separate the "collection" from creating and adding a new instance of "lookaheadRunInfo"

Tags: c#

I am trying to "collect" the GetString(2) until GetString(0) changes,so am trying to find out how to separate the "collection" from creating and adding a new instance of "lookaheadRunInfo"?I have tried as below which throws an exception
`System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` at line 
`lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits.Add(rdr.GetString(1));` ,can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this issue?

```
       try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();

            string sql = @"select lr.ec_job_link, cl.change_list ,lr.submitted_by, lr.submission_time,lr.lookahead_run_status
                                from lookahead_run as lr, lookahead_run_change_list as lrcl, change_list_details as cld,change_lists as cl
                                where lr.lookahead_run_status is null
                                and lr.submission_time is not null
                                and lrcl.lookahead_run_id = lr.lookahead_run_id
                                and cl.change_list_id = lrcl.change_list_id
                                and cl.change_list_id not in (select clcl.change_list_id from component_labels_change_lists as clcl)
                                and cld.change_list_id = lrcl.change_list_id
                                group by lr.lookahead_run_id, cl.change_list
                                order by lr.submission_time desc
                                limit 1000
                                ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var ECJoblink_previous ="";
            var gerritList = new List<String>();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + " -- " + rdr[1]);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                var lookaheadRunInfo = new LookaheadRunInfo();
                lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink = rdr.GetString(0);
                if (ECJoblink_previous == lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink)
                {
                    //Keep appending the list of gerrits until we get a new lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink
                    lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits.Add(rdr.GetString(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits = new List<string> { rdr.GetString(1) };
                }
                ECJoblink_previous = lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink;
                lookaheadRunInfo.UserSubmitted = rdr.GetString(2);
                lookaheadRunInfo.SubmittedTime = rdr.GetString(3).ToString();
                lookaheadRunInfo.RunStatus = "null";
                lookaheadRunInfo.ElapsedTime = (DateTime.UtcNow-rdr.GetDateTime(3)).ToString();
                lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo);                  
            }

            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: The problem is with `lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits`. The gerrits property is not initialize here that's why it throws  nullreferenceexception. You need to initialize it as `lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits= new List <string>();` before the if block.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - correct but if I do that it will keep initializing for every while loop which I dont want...I want to use the initialization in the else part and keep appending to  it.... basically as stated in my question I want to seperate the collection and initialization,how to do that?

Comment: I am not sure if the logic here. You are creating a new instance of LookaheadRunInfo in each iteration. So it will gerrits of it will be null for sure and it will result in error when it go to if block. May be you can check if the property is null before setting it to a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you wish to keep a single `lookaheadRunInfo` for several rows of the resultset, until GetString(0) changes.  Is that right?

In that case you have some significant logic problems.  The way it is written, even if we fix the null reference, you will get a new `lookaheadRunInfo` with each and every row.

Try this:

```
string ECJoblink_previous = null;
LookAheadRunInfo lookaheadRunInfo = null;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (ECJoblink_previous != rdr.GetString(0))  //A new set of rows is starting
    {
        if (lookaheadRunInfo != null)
        {
            lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo); //Save the old group, if it exists
        }
        lookaheadRunInfo = new LookAheadRunInfo     //Start a new group and initialize it
        {
            ECJobLink = rdr.GetString(0),
            gerrits = new List<string>(),
            UserSubmitted = rdr.GetString(2),
            SubmittedTime = rdr.GetString(3).ToString(),
            RunStatus = "null",
            ElapsedTime = (DateTime.UtcNow-rdr.GetDateTime(3)).ToString()
        }
    }
    lookahead.gerrits.Add(rdr.GetString(1));   //Add current row
    ECJoblink_previous = rdr.GetString(0);     //Keep track of column 0 for next iteration
}
if (lookaheadRunInfo != null)
{
    lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo); //Save the last group, if there is one
}
```

The idea here is:

1. Start with a blank slate, nothing initialized
2. Monitor column 0.  When it changes (as it will on the first row), save any old list and start a new one
3. Add to current list with each and every iteration
4. When done, save any remaining items in its own list.  A null check is required in case the reader returned 0 rows.

Comment: did you mean to close the `}` after the `if (lookaheadRunInfo != null)` block

Comment: ?  There are two blocks which match that description, and both appear properly closed to me.

Comment: this works,few questions...where are we making `lookaheadRunInfo` null again to when a new set of rows starting again

Comment: We don't.  We set `lookaheadRunInfo` to a new instance when a new set of rows starts.  There is no reason to set it to null.